# How to use Firebase Firestore .push() method in Javascript front end

Tags: javascript, list, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So let me start by saying Google's Firebase documentation is horrible. I am trying to append child values to a list stored on a document in Firestore db when a user adds an item to their cart on an eCommerce site. Simplest thing ever (or should be).. All of the documentation says to use .push() and there is not one actionable example of how to implement it. This is not enough for me to understand how to use it:

```
// Create a new post reference with an auto-generated id
var newPostRef = postListRef.push();
newPostRef.set({
    // ...
});
```

Where does postListRef come from and how do I instantiate a reference that works with .push()? I've been flat out guessing for the last 3 days off and on about how to use the function, from getting the database reference to adding a value. Below are 2 of the ways I have tried to use it. This is such a stupidly simple question and it drives me insane that after hours of googling there is absolutely not one complete example anywhere I could find. Please offer a complete explanation with sample code in what may seem to be an unnecessary level of detail to you on how to implement .push() with firestore in a vanilla javascript front end script! Bonus points if you can explain how to remove a single item from the list as well.

Documentation Links: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data,
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
//set with a function that checks to see if user is logged in
var userUid;
//set if the user is not signed in to persist the cart
var guestUid;

function addItemToCart() {
        console.log("Add item to cart triggered..");
        const productName = "Assorted Oranges";
        const productId = "123";

        if (userUid != null) {
            var testRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Carts').doc(userUid).push();
            testRef.set({
            productName: productName,
            productId: productId });
        } else {
            guestUid = getUUID();
            var testRef = db.push({
                productName: productName,
                productId: productId
            });
        }
    }
```

No matter how I try to use it I keep getting a variation of the error: .push() is not a function like:

```
product-single:126 Uncaught TypeError: firebase.firestore(...).collection(...).doc(...).push is not a function
    at addItemToCart (product-single:126)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `push()` method is part of the Firebase Realtime Database API, not of the Firestore API. While both databases are part of Firebase, they each have their own API and are not compatible.

To [add a document to a Firestore collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data), you'd do something like:

```
var testRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Carts').doc(userUid);
testRef.set({
  productName: productName,
  productId: productId 
});
```

Comment: I see I was looking at the wrong documentation.. oops. Wish it was more clear. One has to use merge with firestore to achieve the desired behavior: var setWithMerge = cityRef.set({
    capital: true
}, { merge: true });

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data ^

Comment: That'd be the equivalent of RTDB's `update()` method, but yeah... if you want to merge the new fields with any existing values into the document that'd be the way to go.